# Merge two observable streams to generate final array of object

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a HTTP service which returns me following data: ([stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f44z7c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts))

```
[
   {
      "customerId":"114860",
      "customerName":"John Dyer",
      "dateOfBirth":"1987-07-19",
      "emailId":"john.dyer@outlook.vom",
      "mobileNo":"6502789426"
   },
   {
      "customerId":"114861",
      "customerName":"Jason Cook",
      "dateOfBirth":"1988-09-22",
      "emailId":"Jason.Cook2@cognizant.com",
      "mobileNo":"6002789426"
   },
   ... and so on

]
```

After getting above response I want to make another HTTP call to fetch details corresponding to `customerId` which returns me following data(let's say for customerId : 114860) :

```
[  
   {  
      "offerId":"Offer1",
      "offerName":"Wok_Express",
      "offerUrl":"wok_express.png",
      "offerDescription":"Get 10%  discount. Pizzeria where chefs in striped t-shirts toss handmade pizzas."
   },
   {  
      "offerId":"Offer3",
      "offerName":"Only",
      "offerUrl":"only.png",
      "offerDescription":"Get 15% off on refrigerators, washing machine and LED TVs. Get 10% off on all other gadgets"
   },
   {  
      "offerId":"Offer5",
      "offerName":"MakeMyTrip",
      "offerUrl":"MakeMyTrip.png",
      "offerDescription":"Up to Rs. 3000 cashback* on hotels on MakeMyTrip. Offer valid on a min rate of INR 5000."
   },
   {  
      "offerId":"Offer7",
      "offerName":"High_5_Gifts",
      "offerUrl":"high_5_gifts.png",
      "offerDescription":"Saving 15%* up to Rs 350 on first booking of High 5 Gifts. Visit the nearest store for details"
   }
]
```

Now I want to merge above two streams so that it will give me following result data :

```
 [  
   {  
      "customerId":"114860",
      "customerName":"John Dyer",
      "dateOfBirth":"1987-07-19",
      "emailId":"john.dyer@outlook.vom",
      "mobileNo":"6502789426",
      "offers":[  
         {  
            "offerId":"Offer1",
            "offerName":"Wok_Express",
            "offerUrl":"wok_express.png",
            "offerDescription":"Get 10%  discount. Pizzeria where chefs in striped t-shirts toss handmade pizzas."
         },
         {  
            "offerId":"Offer3",
            "offerName":"Only",
            "offerUrl":"only.png",
            "offerDescription":"Get 15% off on refrigerators, washing machine and LED TVs. Get 10% off on all other gadgets"
         },
         {  
            "offerId":"Offer5",
            "offerName":"MakeMyTrip",
            "offerUrl":"MakeMyTrip.png",
            "offerDescription":"Up to Rs. 3000 cashback* on hotels on MakeMyTrip. Offer valid on a min rate of INR 5000."
         },
         {  
            "offerId":"Offer7",
            "offerName":"High_5_Gifts",
            "offerUrl":"high_5_gifts.png",
            "offerDescription":"Saving 15%* up to Rs 350 on first booking of High 5 Gifts. Visit the nearest store for details"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "customerId":"114861",
      "customerName":"Jason Cook",
      "dateOfBirth":"1988-09-22",
      "emailId":"Jason.Cook2@cognizant.com",
      "mobileNo":"6002789426",
      "offers": [ //array of object of offers for 114861]
   },
   ...and so on
]
```

To obtain above result set; I used concatMap (tried mergeMap as well) here:

```
this.commonService.getAllCustomers().pipe(
      concatMap(response => {
        return this.commonService.fetchCustomerOffers(response['customerId']).pipe(
          map(d => {
            response['offers'] = d;
            return response;
          }),
        );
      })
    ).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);

    });
```

but above code run only once..not for all customerId.
Kindly help. I have created stackblitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make each element with customerId to be emitted separstely wiyh mergeAll. In that case it will work as you expect

```
   this.allData = this.commonService.getAllCustomers().pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      concatMap(response => {
        return this.commonService.fetchCustomerOffers(response['customerId']).pipe(
          map(d => {
            response['offers'] = d;
            return response;
          }),
        );
      }),
      scan((x, next) => x.concat([next]), [])
    )
```

see  [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mw6fh5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks this works... 
Now I want to bind this result data set in HTML using async pipe but HTML is not binding giving error. please see this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f44z7c?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I removed subscribtion and i believe above function will return observable so binded with async pipe in *ngFor..

Comment: In that case we should accumulate all the emitted values in array with scan operator. I will correct my answer and slackblitz

Comment: mergeAll and other higher-order observables functions are reviewed also in my video course https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video